# WSO2 Identity Server - Issues with XACML V.3 Policy Set under the Try-It of PAP

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, alfa, wso2-identity-server

I'd like to add a policy set in order to run a series of policies in sequence using a target which defines if a given policy is applicable, or not, based on the input field "resource". To begin a test I wrote a single policySet that contains one policy.

The evaluation by the WSO2 PAP fails showing a result of "NotApplicable" while I expect to receive a "Permit".

Here the policy named "cfatest0" created in XML:

```
<!--This file was generated by the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com).  Any modification to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file-->
   <xacml3:Policy xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="cfatest0" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-overrides" Version="1.0">
      <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
      <xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
         <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
      </xacml3:PolicyDefaults>
      <xacml3:Target>
         <xacml3:AnyOf>
            <xacml3:AllOf>
               <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TPS_AE_REST_Policy</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                  <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
               </xacml3:Match>
            </xacml3:AllOf>
         </xacml3:AnyOf>
      </xacml3:Target>
      <xacml3:Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.red.XACML.permitAll">
         <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
         <xacml3:Target></xacml3:Target>
      </xacml3:Rule>
      <xacml3:Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="http://axiomatics.com/alfa/identifier/com.red.XACML.checkId">
         <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
         <xacml3:Target></xacml3:Target>
         <xacml3:Condition>
            <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:not">
               <xacml3:Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
                  <xacml3:Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"></xacml3:Function>
                  <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">claudef@br.red.com</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                  <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
               </xacml3:Apply>
            </xacml3:Apply>
         </xacml3:Condition>
         <xacml3:ObligationExpressions>
            <xacml3:ObligationExpression ObligationId="obligation.displayAttributes" FulfillOn="Deny">
               <xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
                  <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Access denied due to invalid UserID</xacml3:AttributeValue>
               </xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression>
            </xacml3:ObligationExpression>
         </xacml3:ObligationExpressions>
      </xacml3:Rule>
      <xacml3:AdviceExpressions>
         <xacml3:AdviceExpression AdviceId="advice.displayAttributes" AppliesTo="Deny">
            <xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
               <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Valid subjectId</xacml3:AttributeValue>
            </xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression>
         </xacml3:AdviceExpression>
         <xacml3:AdviceExpression AdviceId="advice.displayAttributes" AppliesTo="Permit">
            <xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:example:attribute:text" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
               <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Valid subjectId</xacml3:AttributeValue>
            </xacml3:AttributeAssignmentExpression>
         </xacml3:AdviceExpression>
      </xacml3:AdviceExpressions>
   </xacml3:Policy>
```

Here the PolicySet named cfapolicyset1 created in XML:

```
<!--This file was generated by the ALFA Plugin for Eclipse from Axiomatics AB (http://www.axiomatics.com).  Any modification to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source ALFA file-->
   <xacml3:PolicySet xmlns:xacml3="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicySetId="cfapolicyset1" PolicyCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:policy-combining-algorithm:permit-overrides" Version="1.0">
      <xacml3:Description></xacml3:Description>
      <xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
         <xacml3:XPathVersion>http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116</xacml3:XPathVersion>
      </xacml3:PolicySetDefaults>
      <xacml3:Target>
         <xacml3:AnyOf>
            <xacml3:AllOf>
               <xacml3:Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <xacml3:AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TPS_AE_REST_Policy</xacml3:AttributeValue>
                  <xacml3:AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" MustBePresent="false"></xacml3:AttributeDesignator>
               </xacml3:Match>
            </xacml3:AllOf>
         </xacml3:AnyOf>
      </xacml3:Target>
      <xacml3:PolicyIdReference>cfatest0</xacml3:PolicyIdReference>
   </xacml3:PolicySet>
```

Below the request generated by the WSO2 "Try-It" tool under the PAP:

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">claudef@br.red.com</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
    <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
        <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">TPS_AE_REST_Policy</AttributeValue>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Request>
```

Decision is:  NotApplicable

Do I miss something in the way how I use to send a request to a PolicySet? When using the WSO2 high level policy editor, I get the same error at the response. When testing the policy isolated in the PAP "Try-It" tool, I receive the correct value, which for this policy is: "Permit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your request and policies inside the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point and I get the desired response i.e. **Permit + Advice**.

[image: Simulation result in the Axiomatics Policy Administration Point]

Could it be you forgot to load the policy inside WSO2IS?

Comment: Thanks for testing the case @David Brossard, your hint was correct, The policies referenced in the PolicyReference statements must be present inside the source code of the PolicySet, placed right after the statement:  xacml3:PolicyIdReference. Having the source available in one XML file, the WSO2 PAP tool is able to interpret it correctly, without need of loading the set and referenced policies into the PDP. This is helpful for testing.